# Javascript Z-Index

Tags: javascript, z-index

I'm having a problem with a jquery snow falling effect and a nivo slider. The problem seems to be that the snow falls behind the slider images, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the z-index of the snow falling effect.

I don't know much about Javascript so am not sure how to change the z-index of it.

Can anyone help with this? Here is a [link](http://www.clickstream.ie/index-test.php), I can post code if needed.

Thanks.
Al.

Comment: Yes, please post your code here. The `z-index` is a CSS property, so you will set it in javascript as you would a color or a dimension: `….style.zIndex`

Comment: The snow flakes plugin is not very well written. Each snow flake is with id `flake`. I suggest to set `flake` as class not as id. After that you can easily set it's z-index.

Comment: well the div#contentArea could by styled as position:relative;z-index:0; seemed to fix the problem for me..

Comment: The server is down. Please post the codes here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will fix the issue by using (of course you should apply it each time you create a new snow flakes...):

```
$("div:contains('❄')").css('z-index', 200);
```

Anyway, it's not a good solution. I use it because each snow flake on the screen is with id `flake`. I suggest you to set class name instead of id (or at least to set unique ids).

Comment: Thanks all for the quick replies, wasn't expecting any so soon. I've tried ppsreejith's comment - position:relative;z-index:0; - and it has worked.

Thanks again and Happy Christmas!